# Apache spark - dealing with auto-updating inputs

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark

I'm new to spark and using it a lot recently to do some batch processing. 
Currently I have a new requirement and am stuck on how to approach it. 
I have a file which has to be processed but this file can get periodically updated. I want the initial file to be processed and as and when there is an update to the file, I want spark operations to be triggered and should operate only on the updated parts  this time. Any way to approach this would be helpful. An
I'm open to using any other technology in combination with spark. The files will generally sit on a  file system and could be several GBs in size.

Answer (score 0):

Spark alone cannot recognize if a file has been updated.
It does its job when reading for a first time the file and that's all.

By default, Spark won't know that a file has been updated and won't know which parts of the file are updates.

You should rather work with folders, Spark can run on a folder and can recognize if there is a new file to process in it -> sc.textFile(PATH_FOLDER)...